# Is it illegal to claim an address as your "primary residence" if you don't live there most of the time?

Tags: united-states, tax-law, real-estate, fraud, homeownership

I currently live and work in NJ. I am single and live with my parents. The apartment we currently live in is small and I want to buy a house, but my state is pretty expensive.

My parents found a nice house in MD but it is about 140 miles away from my office. My plan is to have my parents live in this house and I plan on "living" in both the MD house and my apartment in NJ. I can work from home one day a week, so I will be in MD Friday to Sunday, and in NJ Monday to Thursday.

Now supposing I claim that MD home as my "primary residence" to get the best rates on a mortgage and for taxes, I would change my driving license and voter registration to that state.  Would that be considered "fraud" or "illegal"?

I do live there, just not all the time, maybe 35% of my time.

I can't seem to find any legal defintion of a "primary residence", [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_residence) says "Criteria for a primary residence consist mostly of guidelines rather than hard rules, and residential status is often determined on a case-by-case basis."

Comment: Residence is also determined on a purpose-by-purpose basis.  Your residence for income tax purposes and for driver licensing purposes (for example) and for other purposes might be different.

Comment: There may be an element of intent in this question, too. Where do you intend to live? That's a factor in civil procedure, of course, and would only be relevant if, like @phoog stated would be determined based on the rules/regs related to taxes and driver's licenses.